# Calculate sum of numbers on matrix diagonal

Tags: c#, matrix

I have a dynamic matrix and I need to to calculate sum of digits in this way:

**0 1** 2 3 4 5 6

10 **11 12** 13 14 15 16

20 21 **22 23** 24 25 26

30 31 32 **33 34** 35 36

40 41 42 43 **44 45** 46

50 51 52 53 54 **55 56**

60 61 62 63 64 65 **66**

I can't understand in which way I should compare `i` and `j`:

```
long result = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < len; j++)
    {
        // only works for diagonal
        if (i == j) // should use j - 1 or i - 1? 
        {
            result += matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**no need to scan full matrix**:

```
long result = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
     result += matrix[i][i];      // diagonal
     if (i < len - 1)             // stay within array bounds
        result += matrix[i][i+1]; // next to diagonal
}
```

---

> modification without index check on every iteration:

```
// assign corner value from bottom row to result
long result = matrix[len-1][len-1];
// for each row (except last!) add diagonal and next to diagonal values
for (int i = 0; i < len-1; i++)    
     result += matrix[i][i] + matrix[i][i+1];
```